# Head First Rails| Added a column, changed files, nothing show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm studying Head First Rails Chapter 1, and I followed the instructions to add a column(phone) to a table(tickets) and then change _form.html.erb, index.html.erb and show.html.erb. 
But the browser only shows label without data.
my rails version is 4.0.2
Here's what I did. Please tell me what's wrong with it. Thank you

1.rails g migration AddPhoneToTickets phone:string

2.rake db:migrate

3.Adding the following to _form.html.erb

```
<p>
 <%= f.label :phone %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :phone %>
</p>
```

4.Adding the following to show.html.erb

```
<p>
 <strong>Phone</strong>
 <%= @ticket.phone %>
</p>
```

5.Adding the following to index.html.erb

```
<tr>  
  <th>Phone</th>
</tr>

<% for ticket in @tickets %>
  <tr>
      <td><%= ticket.phone %></td>
  </tr>
```

----------------------------------------

This is my migration file

```
class AddPhoneToTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :tickets, :phone, :string
  end
end
```

-----------------------------------------

I googled this
Also add “:phone” to the list of attributes after attr_accessible in ticket.rb model file. if using Rails 3.2.8 or above
And i tried to add it to /app/models/ticket.rb

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accesible :phone
end
```

my browser shows
undefined method 'atrr_accessible'
what should i do?

Comment: please add your migration file code also..

Comment: Did you add `phone` to `attr_accessible` of your `Ticket` model?

Comment: what version of rails you are using. if it is rails4 then it will use strong_parameters for default . so for storing that you have to permit that through strong_parameters.

Comment: I'm using rails 4.0.2.could you please tell me how to permit?

Comment: do you mean add it to ticket.rb? i only see class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using rails 4, you will not have attr_acessible. you need to check for the line 
params.require(:ticket).permit()
and add :phone to the list of permitted parameters

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit tickets_controller.rb to reflect the new field?

```
def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:name, :seat_id_seq, :address, :price_paid, :email_address, :phone)
end
```

KR